# how to check mssql existing table in php

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know how can I check whether the selected table in mssql is exist by php??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following SQL query should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'SomeTableName'"
```

Should return a count of 0 if it doesn't exist or 1 if it does.

Use with [`msql_query`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.msql-query.php) or [`sqlsrv_query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184%28SQL.90%29.aspx) as appropriate.